# Proteus 3D model not available

Tags: components, design, proteus

I want to add 3d model (step file) to a component in proteus. But I cant get 3d model option when i right click component. I'm currently in proteus 8.13 installed in windows 10.
I also tried another version but same.
Anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: Are you creating the component, or are you editing an existing one? I believe you need to do it from the schematic layout page, bud use the packaging tool

Comment: i want to edit existing one, in just add download tda2050 ic from snapeda but no 3d model for it. So any way to add 3d model? and why my proteus didnt show 3d model option?

Comment: There isn't a straight up "add 3D model" option. I believe you need to use the packaging tool in the PCB layout (not schematic, I got that wrong). I can check later when I can have it open

Comment: yes your're right. I should in PCB layout to do that, long time away from proteus and I've forget that. Thanks bro.

Comment: Ok, that's good. I'll write it up as an answer as that was the solution. I wasn't too sure so had to check first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update 3D models, you need to do this from the PCB layout, not schematic. Right click the components, and use the Packaging Tool. This will give you the options you need to add a 3D model